# What is causing rust-like stains on my stainless steel appliances?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, corrosion

Two weeks ago we discovered that our new Kohler faucet was leaking under the sink in our lanudry room adjacent to our kitchen. We shut off the water and have not used the sink.   It apparently was also leaking into the household cleaning chemical tray including Comet Cleanser for some time.  The entire compartment under the sink was significanlty rusted, including hinges and metal components of the new sink.

Concurrently, we noticed a rust-like coating on our stainless steel microwave above the sink.  In the past two weeks, the coating has spread to our Stainless refrigerator (3 feet away through a doorway), the stove (5' away) and other stainless surfaces, some up to 10' away in a separate room.

There is no noticeable odor or other indications.  The coating can be removed with spray stainless steel cleaner.   Other surfaces do not seem to be impacted.

Any suggestions on what could be causing this chemical reaction?

Comment: Please post a picture.

Comment: What is a Kohler faucet ? Why is it under the sink ? What is a chemical tray ? What is Comet Cleanser ? Why do you speak of a new sink ? Why new ? Why do you put a microwave above the sink ? How are the stainless pieces related ? Are they related ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with the Comet smell, that may be the culprit.

Comet contains a relatively volatile, odorous bleaching compound, [trichloroisocyanuric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichloroisocyanuric_acid). This compound is a form of chlorine bleach. As such, when it reacts with stains or perchance with metals it can reach via evaporation and travel through the air, it releases chloride ions -- which then break down the passive layer that's supposed to keep stainless steel from rusting.

To minimize this condition, thoroughly rinse this cleanser off and drain it after cleaning.

Comment: I don't think that trichloroisocyanuric acid would readily sublime, and chloride ions don't go floating through the air. So I'd think the decomposition of trichloroisocyanuric acid with water (or humid air) would yield *chlorine gas*  rather than *chloride ions.*

Comment: The fact that it is odorous implies some vapor pressure, and I do not claim the chloride ions flost through the air. The latter would form at the reaction site.